# C# .Net 4 Retrieve shared folders

Tags: c#, .net, shared-directory

I'm creating a WPF file explorer treeview (in C# 4) and I need it to work with UNC. For example, lets say I have these shared networks folders:

```
\\share\test1
\\share\test2
\\share\test3
\\share\test4
```

If I only have `\\share`, how can I determine what shared folders are within that path? \share is not a shared folder in and of itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/networkshares.aspx. This contains an explanation with working source code.

Comment: Wouldn't hurt to provide them here.

Answer (score 2):

use WMI as bellow:

```
using (System.Management.ManagementClass shareObj = new
System.Management.ManagementClass("Win32_Share"))
{
  System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection shares =
  shareObj.GetInstances();

  foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject share in shares)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + share["Name"].ToString());
  }
}
```